# NodeJS on Windows 10 and Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: node.js, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get Expo, a platform for making native mobile apps, to run on a Windows 10 machine.  A preprequisite for Expo is NodeJS so I installed that.  However, I ran into some issues getting Expo to work using Git Bash and so now I'm trying to get Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) operational to use that instead.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has been downloaded and initialized.  Using a CMD here is what's happening:

```
C:\Users\jason.black>node -v
v12.13.0

C:\Users\jason.black>wsl
jason@PC1:/mnt/c/Users/jason.black$ node -v

Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs

jason@PC1:/mnt/c/Users/jason.black$ sudo apt install nodejs
[sudo] password for jason:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
jason@PC1:/mnt/c/Users/jason.black$
```

So it appears that NodeJS which was initially installed is not available to WSL.  Does that seem right?  And why won't it install so WSL can access it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access Node installed on the windows site, you may specify the PATH to /mnt/x/.../path/to/node/bin; if you're trying to install nodejs on the Linux side, may be you're looking for the package 'node' (not nodejs), or you can just download the portable version: https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.13.1/node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz

For someone who's not familiar to Linux:

```
# will be download to home directory
cd ~
# using wget
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.13.1/node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
# using curl
curl -o node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.13.1/node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
# extract
tar xf node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Comment: Will the version that was initially installed interfere with the portable version?  Is there a way to download the portable version only on the Linux side?

Comment: you can access windows side files under `/mnt/x`, and by default everything outside that is on the linux side ( in WSL1 it is under some directory in AppCache / in WSL2 it is in a virtual disk);  You can install mutiple version of node, as long as they reside in different path ( And do not specify both of them in PATH).  May be you can use NVM (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) which can control the version switches for you.

Comment: You can just use `wget` / `curl` on the linux side to download, or just download the file from windows, and `cp` to Linux.

Comment: Would it be possible to add to your answer how to use `wget` / `curl` on the Linux side to download NodeJS?  That would help alot...I'm a newbie at Linux (though that is probably evident).

Comment: The edit is much appreciated.  One clarifying question - what is considered the home directory?  C:?  C:\Users\jason.black?  Something else?

Comment: the `~` home directory is on the Linux side, and as said earlier, WSL1/WSL2 has different locations for that. You can access Linux files on windows using Explorer ( after 1903, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/ )